# Dropdown menu disappear when i'm trying to hover the list

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, pug

I have an issue with dropdown menu. I've tried different solutions, but seems that no one of them works. I'm using SCSS, and i need that my dropdown menu keep being active once i hover the burger menu.

What happen is that whenever i hover it, it disappear after moving the mouse out of the div.
Here is my code:

```
    .burger {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    &:before{
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
        font-weight: 900; 
        content: "\f0c9";
        margin-right: .2rem;
    }
    &:after{
        content: 'Menu';
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    &:hover .dropdown, .dropdown:hover {
        display: block;
        z-index: 99;
    }
}
.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    top: calc(5vh - 1px);
    right: -10vw;
    background: black;

}
```

This is my template, using Pug.js Template Engine:

```
            ul.mobile 
            div.burger
                div.dropdown
                    ul
                        each item in navigation
                            li
                                i(class=item.icon)
                                a(href=item.link)= item.name
```

Thank you very much for your help!

https://codepen.io/makkoyev/pen/abojxvG

Comment: can you please a working demo ?

Comment: @piyushjain Sure! Let me try it on codepen, and will update the post!

Comment: You need a continuous “path” from your parent trigger element to your sub menu, that you can follow with your mouse cursor – any “holes” or breaks in it would mean you are not hovering the parent element any more, so it breaks at that point. Still no example, but with `.burger` positioned relative and then `.dropdown` absolute, I guess you might not have that here.

Comment: I've added the codepen example. I've fixed it by adding padding to .burger, but i don't know if it's ok to do it. In live version is quite different, as i'm using @media and adapt everything, but hope you got the idea!

Comment: @04FS What do you mean for 'holes'?

Comment: Elements being positioned in a way where you can not follow a continuous path from parent to child.